# How can I get rid of **index.html** in prompt window?

Tags: javascript

As long as styling **prompt window** is not possible with JS alone, can I at least hide **index.html** text?

```
prompt('Enter Something');
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nope. You can't do **anything** to customize the appearance of the `prompt` dialog, at all. You can't add to it (other than the prompt), remove from it, style it, etc.

Which is, of course, one reason not to use it, but instead to show your own dialog with styled markup, etc., and handle the fact you'll get your input asynchronously rather than synchronously. This is fairly easy to do yourself, but there are also roughly 175,341 libraries out there happy to help you do it. :-)